# update community cookbook versions that I am not pulling in directly

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I am refreshing some Chef builds that I haven't run in a long time.

As expected I am encountering errors, but so far in community cookbooks that I don't reference directly.  How do I use more recent versions of them to make the errors hopefully go away.

For example, I was previously at build-essential 3.2.0 (some cookbooks were pulling it in) and I am getting a compile error on [build-essential](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/build-essential).  Build-essential is currently at 8.0.3

My plan is currently to get the build to succeed by changing as little as possible, so I'd rather not refresh community cookbooks until I hit an error with them.  Once things are working with the community cookbooks I will a) fix my actual build issues first and b) refresh the community cookbooks as much as possible.

In this case, **build-essential** does hit an error and I want to update it.

But cookbooks that depend on build-essential are not necessarily asking for recent **build-essential**:

```
 monit-ng-2.3.3/metadata.json:    "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
 runit-1.5.10/metadata.json:    "build-essential": ">= 0.0.0",
```

Given that, when I do a `berks update build-essential`, the it stays at 3.2.0

To actually bump it up to recent versions, I had to add this to my own **Berksfile**:

```
#cookbook bump forcing:
cookbook 'build-essential', '~>8.0'
cookbook 'ohai', '~>5.2'
```

Is there a better way?  Should I instead start out by refreshing all my direct community cookbook dependencies?  I.e. in the above, **monit-ng** and **runit** both have more recent cookbook versions, so those might in turn request recent **build-essential**

Comment: If you're on a very old version of cookbooks, are you also on an older version of Berks?

Comment: i dont think so.  i reinstalled the whole chefdk recently, this was a from-scratch macos rebuild. but is that maybe something i can affect by deleting Berksfile.lock, to unpin the versions?  but that would trigger refreshes across the board.

Comment: Does anything else in the lock file show a dependency on build-essential?

Comment: Ah.   **postgresql (6.1.1) build-essential (>= 2.0.0)** might be causing this.  so, `berks update` should do the trick, **but** it has to meet the various constraints, so that's why it was not happening?  makes sense.